# How do I do custom forms in Sitecore MVC?

Tags: mvc, mvc-forms

I am trying to get a form in my MVC Controller Rendering to work.
I have read these posts:

https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/30/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-2-controller-renderings/

https://ctor.io/posting-forms-in-sitecore-controller-renderings-another-perspective/

I have tried these form options

My controller

```cs
public class VacanciesController : SitecoreController
{
    public ActionResult VacancyDetail()
    {
        var model = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.GetRenderingModel<VacancyDetailModel>();
        var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        return this.View(model);
    }
}
```

with this attribute

```cs
public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    var controller = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fhController"];
    var action = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fhAction"];

    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action)
            && controller == controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Name
            && methodInfo.Name == action;
}
```

this is my view form code

```razor
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{                     
    <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-highlight" type="submit">Solliciteer direct empty form</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="fhController" value="Vacancies" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fhAction" value="VacancyDetail" />
}
```

This seems to work now

```razor
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Vacancies", "VacancyDetail")            
    <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-highlight" type="submit">Solliciteer direct routeform</button>
}
```

this goes to the correct controller and action.
Bu my RenderingContext.Current.Rendering is null

```razor
@using (Html.BeginForm("VacancyDetail", "Vacancies", new { id = "1" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-highlight" type="submit">Solliciteer direct routeform</button>
}
```

This goes to the correct controller and action. 
But Sitecore.Contect.item is null & RenderingContext.Current.Rendering is null

What is the correct way to create a custom form?

Comment: Are you using the `Controller` or `SitecoreController` as base class to your controller, and how have you defined your controller rendering in Sitecore?

Comment: Just a small note - The last behavior you are mentioning, is explained in Martina's blogpost you've linked to.

Comment: I am using controller as base class.
I have created a controller rendering with controller name and action Same as for the get

Comment: Okay, so you have both a HttpGet and HttpPost action in your controller named the same as defined in the controller rendering?

Comment: I added my controller code

Comment: A few other notes, while poking my brain: The other approach with calling Html.BeginForm() with params will cause you to hit the controller directly, and thereby bypassing Sitecore's routing. This will cause the effect you see where the rendering is null, as far as I remember. If your post was working you'd see that you would hit the controller directly in the URL, and that all your content (e.g renderings) was missing.

Comment: I changed the action on my controller. First form Html.BeginForm() is now working as expected I have rendering context and sitecore context. The begin routeform has no rendering context

Comment: Could you try having the same action method twice, one for get and one for post? let the post method take the ViewModel as parameter, and be sure to explicitly set the[HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes on the methods accordingly, and test out the same approach you got working now?

Comment: When I have the same action twice the first form: Html.BeginForm()  is working. The second: BeginRouteForm has no rendering context

Comment: Right, that makes sense, as it would be the same issue as when you call Html.BeginForm with parameters as I described in the above. Normally what I do is use the first approach (the one you got working now). I usually have the same method action defined twice, one for Get and one for Post, and in the post version I pass in the ViewModel, which I then rebuild the same way you are doing it. So to answer your question, given that you want to post to your controller and that you want to do some model checking and then redirect to the same view with the error message, go with the first approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you can either use the first or second approach.

I'm normally using the first approach (the one you got working now) for these sorts of things. What I do is having the same method action defined twice, one for get and one for the post, and in the post version I pass in the `ViewModel`, which I then rebuild the same way you are doing it. The action methods should be annotated correctly with the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes.

If you use `Html.BeginForm(controller, controllerAction)`, you will experience that you are being redirected to the controller's URL (like `/sitecore/api/{controller}/{action}`), and not the page containing the controller rendering(s), as you'd expect. This is something to keep in mind when doing some sort of model checking, where you want to show the error message in the view, if the model is not valid.

Comment: Is it normal behaviour that in the second option my Current rendering context is null?

Comment: I'm not actually sure about whether or not it's default behaviour in Sitecore's MVC implementation, but I would say it's not default ASP.NET MVC implementation behaviour. Remember that Sitecore MVC is an implementation of ASP.NET MVC, so there are a few key differences. I've noticed this behaviour myself when using the second option, but for some reason the SiteContext.Item is not null, even though the RenderingContext is.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is the one I have used mostly. But for some form submissions we wanted to have the page context as we had to pull data source of some other rendering on the page. So, my two cents would be

- Check if you need page context, if so, pass in the page GUID to be handy
- If possible use MVC Ajax posts to restrict full page reload and exchange only what is required. Even here you can pass the page GUID.

Comment: So always use the first option is the best approach? In that situation I have the page and rendering context